# Trouble with booting machines by bootable USB drive of Windows 10 ISO image

Tags: windows-10, boot, iso-image, bootable-media

I have downloaded [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) image and I'm used `dd` command on Linux to make a bootable USB drive:

```
$ sudo dd if=Win10_1903_V2_English_x64.iso of=/dev/sdc
$ sudo sync
```

I when I try to boot an Asus laptop with the USB drive, it is on the boot menu. However when I select it and press enter, this message is received:

[image: Asus boot message]

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
>
> or Insert Boot media in selected Boot device and press a key

Also tried on a HP ProBook 450 G3, the USB drive is on the boot menu, but when selecting it and pressing enter, a quick black screen is shown and then jump back to boot options.

I wonder what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: The windows 10 download link you provided is the tool to make the bootable usb drive, why not use that?

Comment: Since some time ago the Microsoft ISOs are somehow weird and the traditional tools including DVD cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved by following these instructions to create bootable USB device out of Windows ISO image:

http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/how-to-make-win7-bootable-usb-drive.htm